# Flutter execution failed for task ':app:validatesigningdebug

Tags: flutter

[This is my problem][1]

[1]:

This is the image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIMkz.png

Answer (score 0):

1. flutter doctor -v
2. Then find your java path folder e.g. Java binary at: `C:\Program files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java`
3. Select  `C:\Program files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin`
4. `C:\> C:\Program files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin` Enter
5. now use `keytool` Function

I Hope it could help.